# Using SonarQube Quality profile All PHP CodeSniffer Rules results in 0 issue and 0,0 days of technical debt

Tags: php, sonarqube, phpcodesniffer

I'm using SonarQube 4.0 and when I set a project to be analyzed with All PHP CodeSniffer Rules quality profile, the result is 0 issue and 0,0 days of technical debt.

The project I analyze is a PHP Project.

The other metrics work well like cyclomatic complexity, comments, duplications.

When I use the default quality profile named SonarWay, everything work well but I want to use the other quality profile since it contains a lot more rules.

At first glance there is no issues related to that problem in SonarQube PHP Plugin JIRA.

Answer (score 1):

I add the same issue when i upgrade from sonar 3.5 to 4.2
The quality profile "sonar way" that i was using was "merged" with the new one with 0 rules in quality profile.
I changed it using the new "sonar way" with 47 rules (in my config) and re-run analysis. Then it worked again with relevant results.
I hope it could help